# How to left join and count two tables where the rows (strings) are different

Tags: postgresql

## PostgreSQL 9.5.6

I have two tables - t1, t2.

t1 has a title column with titles separated by spaces.

```
t1.title
--------
hello kitty workd
gone wind forever
```

t2 has a path column with paths separated by dashes and prefixed 'path/'

```
t2.path
-------
path/hello-kitty-world
path/gone-wind-forever
```

**GOAL:** FOR EACH t1.title COUNT THE NUMBER OF TIMES IT SHOWS UP IN t2

**Course of action**: parse t2.path so that it looks like t1.title in order to do a left join and count**

I'm very new to this, if you have a better approach altogether I would appreciate any suggestions

So far I have:

```
select t1.title, count(t2.path) as num 
from t1 left join t2 on t1.title = substring(log.path from 6) 
where t1.title like '%'||split_part(substring(log.path from 6),'-',1)||'%' 
group by articles.title;
```

Comment: Thank you!  btw, do you know how I can shorten a multi-word string to say 3 words?  For all the substring() functions I need to know the index position of the char where I want to start extraction, but the strings I'm working with are varying length.

Comment: @S.Ro Although shortening a multi-word string to 3 words may be related to the question you've asked here, it nevertheless appears to be an entirely different issue. Please don't make a mess out of this thread by raising several distinct issues at once. That multi-word problem looks to me like a perfectly valid question in itself, so, if you need help there, please post a new question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) said in question comments:

> You don't need to split the strings. If there is always a single space between word, you can replace space with `-` and then join: `ON 'path/' || replace(t1.title, ' ', '-') = t2.path`
>
> Or the reverse:  `ON t1.title = replace(substring(t2.path, 6), '-', '')`

You can use [replace()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html) function in the `ON` clause to compare both strings and get the desired result:

> ```
> select     title, path
> from       t1
> inner join t2
> on         'path/' || replace(t1.title, ' ', '-') = t2.path;
> ```
>
> ```
> title             | path                  
> :---------------- | :---------------------
> gone wind forever | path/gone-wind-forever
> ```

> ```
> select     title, path
> from       t1
> inner join t2
> on         t1.title = replace(substring(t2.path, 6), '-', ' ');
> ```
>
> ```
> title             | path                  
> :---------------- | :---------------------
> gone wind forever | path/gone-wind-forever
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e621cfed1266f980edc3a8c30eb888bc)*

Answer (score 0):

Paths as a function of title is perfectly fine. However, using them in a join condition is an anti-pattern. Instead, create a function to generate them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION path_from_title ( IN title text, OUT path text )
AS $$
  SELECT 'path/' || replace($1, ' ', '-');
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql'
STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

Now either join on the natural key (title) which makes things simple, or store a fkey to the title table.

If that doesn't make sense, it's ok to have data as a function of an immutable natural key. Path is `f(title)`. It's weird though to then have to create `g(f(title))` as an inverse of `f(title)` just to do a join.